# How do I offset an element using the 'top' CSS property inside a TD?

Tags: css

So I want to offset an element 5 pixels up. I set `position: absolute` and `top: -5px`. Now the element is positioned relative to the page, not the containing TD tag. Am I understanding [absolute positioning wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)? It does say

> position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned
>   ancestor or to the containing block.

Ancestor is TD, right?

Similarly, the [`top` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) says

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or
>   position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the top margin
>   edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.

So why does this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p225mv2/1/) render the table content block relative to the page, not the TD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a position: relative; in the parent TD element. The TD doesn't include that by default.

JS fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2p225mv2/2/

CSS to fix it:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're missing the part that says: **closest positioned ancestor** with the key word being "positioned".

Add:

```
td {
    position:relative;
}
```

and you'll get this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2p225mv2/3/)**